# Why can only update a factory object, not a variable in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn how to code better in Angular, so please let me know if there is also better ways to do this.

Basically, I have a "toggle" state, which is used on quite a few places around my application. This is stored in a Cookie (I have a service for this), and also update in real time for the user.

My Factory `ToggleFactory`:

```
var toggle = Cookie.check('toggle') ? Cookie.get('toggle') : false;

return {
    state: toggle,
    toggle: function() {
        if(!this.state) {
            Cookie.set('toggle', true);
            this.state = true;
            return true;
        }
        else {
            Cookie.set('toggle', false);
            this.state = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.toggleState = ToggleFactory.state;

$scope.onToggle = function() {
    $scope.toggleState = ToggleFactory.toggle();
};
```

Right so this works, however I know there is a better way of doing this, without returning anything... However, I can only get it working if I update an object bound to `state`, rather than a variable:

```
var obj = {
    toggle: Cookie.check('toggle') ? Cookie.get('toggle') : false;
}

return {
    state: obj,
    toggle: function() {
        if(!this.state) {
            Cookie.set(cookieKey, true);
            obj.toggle = true;
        }
        else {
            Cookie.set(cookieKey, false);
            obj.toggle = false;
        }
    }
};
```

Controller:

```
$scope.rotwState = ToggleFactory.obj.toggle;

$scope.onToggle = function() {
   ToggleFactory.toggle();
};
```

Now this works, as the scope is bound to that object and I can update the object in my factory, which is reflected in the scope.... but why can't I do this with a basic variable?

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: There's a good blog post explaning the differences between objects and primitives in the context of angular js [here](http://stsc3000.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/a-tale-of-frankenstein-and-binding-to-service-values-in-angular-dot-js/)

Comment: Oo thanks, the whole use of factories and services still confuses me :(